# Check Folder as Write access,Air app ,Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air

how to know the folder as write permission in air application..in my application i am saving txt file in folder,so that i need to test that folder as write permission...

var file:File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("TxtFolder/DataFile.txt");

i need to check "TxtFolder" has write permission...? before saving the file(DataFile.txt)..how can i do it in flex Air as3

Thanks In Advance...

Answer (score 1):

You can handle [ioError](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/events/IOErrorEvent.html#IO_ERROR) event which [FileReference](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/net/FileReference.html) dispatches when you don't have permissions to write into directory.

Answer (score 1):

Run the AIR app as administrator and you can even write inside system32 folder of windows. That means anywhere, just anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

You can write to a file with AIR only if the file is under "applicationStorageDirectory".
This is the only folder that has write permision.

If some know more please correct me.

Comment: You can write anywhere the user has permission to write. Across the network, desktop, c:\temp, etc...

Comment: @ JOEL HOOKS: Can you please try to save a file to "Anywhere the user has permissions". In case you do please let me know what magic have you done for it because I receive a nice IOError. Also please provide me a working sample code.

Comment: AIR can't write to applicationDirectory, and to other places where OS forbids it. It has access to much more than storage directory.